# need to see a consolidated output of a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to see  flightid, count of # of tickets for that flight , count of # of staff(airhostess) for that flight.

I am  able to see them by 2 subqueries but unable to see a consolidated view

```
        select f.flightid, count(ticketnum)  from flight f , ticket t 
        where f.actDepartDateTime is not null
        and  f.flightid=t.flightid
        group by f.flightid
        order by 1;


        select f.flightid, count(h.staffid) from flight f ,hosting h
        where f.actDepartDateTime is not null
        and   f.flightid=h.flightID 
        group by f.flightid
        order by 1;
```

Comment: You can use union as well

Comment: Hi, you can union them! See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) in order to understand the union operator.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - use correlated subqueries to do the counting. (No need to worry about many to many relations, multiple joins, flights without tickets etc.)

```
select f.flightid, 
       (select count(*) from ticket t where f.flightid = t.flightid) as cnt_ticketnum, 
       (select count(*) from hosting h where f.flightid = h.flightID) as cnt_staffid
from flight f 
where f.actDepartDateTime is not null           
order by f.flightid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use such an `inner join` statement among all three tables

```
    select f.flightid, 
           count( case when nvl(t.ticketnum,0)>0 then 1 end ) as cnt_ticketnum, 
           count( case when nvl(h.staffid,0)>0   then 1 end ) as cnt_staffid
      from flight f 
      join hosting h on f.flightid=h.flightID 
      join ticket t on f.flightid=t.flightid
     where f.actDepartDateTime is not null           
     group by f.flightid
     order by f.flightid;
```

Comment: But then you would need distinct on h.staffid, wouldn't you?

Comment: thanks  a lot , i tried it but somehow the correct answer for the counts was not coming

Comment: @user2639287 you're welcome. perhaps you may have null values for `t.ticketnum` or `h.staffid`. So, I changed the query.